# Why can't I retrieve URL parameters in tabs.page.ts with ActivatedRoute in my Ionic 4 app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm building an Ionic 4 app and I'm trying to retrieve URL parameters from my tabs page whenever someone clicks the share tab.

With the parameters I can retrieve the correct content, since every day has different content and the date is stated in the URL.

Problem is that whenever I use the `ActivatedRoute` params, im getting an empty object.. This problem is only present in the tabs.page, since on the day-view page itself the content is already showing properly.

Does anyone know why I can retrieve the url params from day-view (which is a child of tabs.page), but can't from the tabs page itself?

Thanks in advance!

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
});
// returns {};

// tabs.router.module.ts

    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'day-view/:month/:day',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: '../day-view/day-view.module#DayViewPageModule'
        }
      ]
    },
   ]
 }
]
```